# How to load a movieclip and goto the first frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I use a button in my header of my website to remove one movieclip (page of my website) off the stage and tweened another onto the page like so...

```
function moviesClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    pageContainer_mc.removeChildAt(1);
    pageContainer_mc.addChild(pMov);
    TransitionManager.start(pageContainer_mc, {type:Photo, direction:Transition.IN, duration:1, easing:None.easeNone}); 
}
```

I have encountered a problem - if i have been on this timeline previously and gone from frame 1 to say frame 2 (another page in that area of my website) when i use the button in my head of my website again, i stay on frame 2 but i want to be returned to frame 1 always when this button is pressed (code above for my button).
How do i force this timeline to start at frame 1 whenever the button in my header (on a seperate timeline) is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the timeline in question the pagecontainer_mc? If so:

```
pageContainer_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
```

*Edit based on comment discussion:*

Assuming that's the correct path, this should work.

```
moviesPage.moviesHolder.moviesNow.gotoAndStop(1);
```

Comment: no its in a movieclip called movies. I tried movies_mc.gotoAndStop(1) within the above function but it didnt work.

Comment: Is "movies" added to stage using addChild()?

Comment: Yes the "movies" movieclip is added to the stage through the addchild function

Comment: Is movies_mc a child of another movieclip? Basically we need to figure our how to target movies_mc and I don't know the hierarchy of your stage & movieclips.

Comment: oh ok.. I think the structure is moviesPage.moviesHolder.moviesNow ... The middle mc is used as a holder to tween between moviesNow and moviesComing. moviesPage is where my actionscript is being written and the timeline i want to affect is moviesNow. Is it just the case of typing the path above followed  by gotoandplay(1)?